# How can i get friends latest status from facebook in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am little bit new at facebook api so my question is, Is there anyway to find the latest status of any facebook friend?

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Regards
Emon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple: **You can´t**. All friend permissions are gone since v2.0, see the changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

This is for privacy reason. No App has any business with the posts of the user friends who did not even authorize that App.